# AWS-CLI - SQS List Queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a policy for an IAM user that was created for sending and receiving messages from a specific SQS queue. When using the AWS CLI and issuing the `list-queues` command I get the error:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListQueues operation: Access to the resource https://queue.amazonaws.com/ is denied.`

I have a custom policy on the IAM user to specify the permissions as shown below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1485992560000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:ListQueues"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:XXXX:TestQueue"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this policy in place, I have verified that I can send and receive messages from this queue using the AWS CLI. If I modify the permissions to the user and add a statement where the Action is `sqs:ListQueues` and the Resource is `"*"` the `list-queues` command using the AWS CLI returns the url for TestQueue in the response.

Am I wrong to think that `list-queue` should return only the queues the IAM user has been granted that action on?

Any guidance/advice welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands such as `sqs:ListQueues` cannot be restricted on their resources. They must have a resource specification of `*`. This also means that you cannot limit the return values: they will always return all queues, even if the user cannot perform actions on them.

This is similar behaviour to other "listing" type methods, like `ec2:DescribeInstances`, etc.